# Possible issue with AutoMapper in MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, automapper

I am trying to fetch the resultset of a stored procedure using Entity Framework database first approach using a stored procedure in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application.

I have set the automapper to map the result object(complex type) with the entities that I have created. The controller return a resulted set with null values. I have used AutoMapper to Map these two objects. I can see the AutoMapper configuration executing prior to fetching the records but dont understand why its not returning values. I have checked the stored procedure in the database and it does return records. Please find the code below.

**Output on the browser**

```
{"Data":[{"TeamID":0,"CountryCode":null,"TeamName":null,"TeamDescription":null,"IsActive":0,"CreatedDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","CreatedBy":null,"ModifiedDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","ModifiedBy":null},{"TeamID":0,"CountryCode":null,"TeamName":null,"TeamDescription":null,"IsActive":0,"CreatedDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","CreatedBy":null,"ModifiedDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","ModifiedBy":null},{"TeamID":0,"CountryCode":null,"TeamName":null,"TeamDescription":null,"IsActive":0,"CreatedDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","CreatedBy":null,"ModifiedDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","ModifiedBy":null},{"TeamID":0,"CountryCode":null,"TeamName":null,"TeamDescription":null,"IsActive":0,"CreatedDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","CreatedBy":null,"ModifiedDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","ModifiedBy":null}],"Total":4,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null}
```

[image]

**Entities defined in the project**

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Team : BaseEntity
{
        public int TeamID { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string  TeamName { get; set; }
        public string TeamDescription { get; set; }
        public int IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Team([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return Json(mcrRepository.GetTeams().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Repository**

```
public class McrRepository
{
        MCREntities db = new MCREntities();

        public List<Team> GetTeams()
        {
            if (ADHelper.UserValidate() == 1)
            {
                var teams = db.spGetAllTeams("");
                return teams.Select(t => new Team()).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
}
```

**Mappings**

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
        public static void Configure()
        {
            Assembly[] assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().OfType<Assembly>().ToArray();
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            cfg.AddProfiles(AllClasses.FromAssemblies(assemblies)
            .Where(
            a =>
               a.FullName.EndsWith("Mapping"))));
        }
}

public class DomainToModelMapping : Profile
{
        public DomainToModelMapping()
        {
             CreateMap<spGetAllTeams_Result, Team>().ReverseMap(); 
        }
}
```

Comment: And where is the mapping? All I see is `teams.Select(t => new Team())` which explains the result you are getting.

Comment: isnt this doing the mapping  CreateMap<spGetAllTeams_Result, Team>().ReverseMap();

Comment: what else do i need to do. Could you show me a sample

Comment: No, it's just configuration. Instead of the above, you should use something like `return Mapper.Map<List<Team>>(teams);`

Comment: I get this error {"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nspGetAllTeams_Result -> Team\r\nCC.GRP.MCRequest.Models.spGetAllTeams_Result -> CC.GRP.MCRequest.Models.Team"}

Comment: That's another story, isn't it? Now make sure the `Configure` method is called, and if yes, make sure that mapping from `spGetAllTeams_Result` to `Team` is configured correctly and works.

Comment: As you can see the entity names in Team and Base entity exactly match the the ones in spGetAllTeams_Result. Infact I had copied the entities from spGetAllTeams and pasted them in Team so that there should be not room for error.

Comment: Sorry, from this point there is nothing we can do w/o [mcve].